# How do you show an alert view for push notifications if the app is not in the foreground or background in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know how to show a push notifications `UIAlertView` if the app is in the background or foreground using the following code:

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSString *message = [ [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]
                         objectForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [ [UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@""
                            message:message
                            delegate:nil
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

However, I also want to show an alert view if the app was completely closed and the user wants to open the app via the push notifications.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't show an alert view if the app is in the background. An alternative would be to have some text in the push notification that tells the user to re-open the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When application launches as a result of a push notification, in other words, when the app was not running, you need to handle that case in `[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if (notification) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Push Notification" message:notification[@"aps"][@"alert"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

---

If the app is in background or foreground (active) state, you need to handle that case in `[AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]` method.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Push Notification" message:userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];
    }
    else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        // Do something else rather than showing an alert view, because it won't be displayed.
    }
}
```

For more information, you can take a look at [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4) from Apple.